# Exclude row names when saving data to a database table

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble, r-dbi

```
#install.packages("rfm")
library(rfm)
#library(data.table)

########Data Preparation
invoice_no <- c('536365','536366','536365','536367')
stock_code <- c('85123A','71053','84406B','84029G')
description <- c('WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER','WHITE METAL LANTERN','CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER','KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE')
quantity <- c(2,5,8,2)
invoice_date <-  c('19/1/10','19/8/11','19/8/11','19/09/11')
unit_price <- c(2.55,3.5,1,0.5)
customer_id <- c(17850,17851, 17850,17000)
country <- c('Nepal','Nepal','Nepal','Nepal')

df <- data.frame(invoice_no,stock_code,description,quantity,invoice_date = as.Date(invoice_date,format = '%y/%m/%d'),unit_price,customer_id,country)
df$total_amount <- df$quantity * df$unit_price

### Calculate RFM 
analysis_date <- lubridate::as_date('2019-9-30', tz = 'UTC')
rfm_result <- rfm_table_order(data = df, customer_id = customer_id, order_date = invoice_date, revenue = total_amount, analysis_date = analysis_date)

### Sunmary of rfm results shown in the following section
summary(rfm_result)
```

[image: Summary of RFM Results]

```
#Dumping the RFM results to database table, table_rfm_output using mydb connection
dbWriteTable(conn = mydb, 
             name = "table_rfm_output", 
             value = (rfm_result$rfm))
```

Results look good in the database table, but I saw additional column, row_names with text datatype in the database table, the definition of table_rfm_out shown in the image as per my example.

[image]

How to avoid the extra column named row_names while dumping the result in the database table? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The following arguments are not part of the dbWriteTable() generic (to improve compatibility across backends) but are part of the DBI specification:

* row.names (default: NA)

Comment: did you try to set `row.names` to FALSE?

Comment: @Bulat - Thank you, setting row.names = FALSE in dbWriteTable() worked.